# vueJs - z-index not working for child div inside v-dialog

Tags: jquery, css, vue.js, z-index

I have brought a span to show loading image inside v-Dialog of vuejs screen. Since the v-dialog has z-index of 220 which is inline style, my new span (loading image) is coming below the v-dialog. I have tried everything but its not working.

I need to show loading image above the v-dialog

[image]

[image: console source]

Comment: `z-index` is used on elements which are positioned (i.e. `absolute`, `relative`, `fixed`). What are you trying to do exactly? If you want to position an element over an other positioned element, you can set the order with `z-index`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Method 1:

Put your loader element inside the `v-dialog` component:

```html
<v-dialog>
  <v-card>
    <div class="loader"/>
    ...
```

```css
.loader {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #fff;
}
```

### Method 2:

Put your loader element in the root component and set the highest z-index you are using in your app so it's displayed above all elements:

### App.vue

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="loader"/>
  ...
```

```css
.loader {
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #fff;
}
```